# A constant for univalent functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f:D\to C$ is univalent holomorphic from the unit disk into the complex plane so that $f(0)=f'(0)-1=0$. What is the precise constant $r$ so that $f(D)$ does not contain the disk $D(0,r)$. Is it $r=1$?

Comment: Perhaps it follows at once from Schwarz lemma that $r=1$.

Comment: The question is not very clear to me, but you may be looking for the [Koebe 1/4 theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem).

Comment: @LukaThaler No, not really. For any such $f$, the minimum modulus of $z\notin f(D)$ is between $1/4$ and $1$; the upper bound indeed follows from Schwarz's lemma, as noted by the OP.

Comment: The question can be restated as: what is the (Euclidean) inradius of a domain with [conformal radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_radius) $1$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are absolutely right! It seems that I've overlooked the condition that maps considered here are univalent.